# Prevent tab navigation for lower z-index controls

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have next xaml:

```
<Grid>
  <local:MyControl1 Grid.Row="0" Panel.Z-Index="1" />
  <local:MyControl12 Grid.Row="1" Panel.Z-Index="1" />
  <local:MyControl21 Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Panel.ZIndex="2" />
  <local:MyControl22 Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Panel.ZIndex="3" />
</Grid>
```

When `MyControl21` is shown, it us under `MyControl1` and `MyControl12`.
When `MyControl22` is shown it is under `MyControl1`, `MyControl12` and `MyControl21`.

I want when I'm using Tab on `MyControl22` only `MyControl22` children controls was selectable. But looks like tabulation selects also lower-level controls from `MyControl21`, `MyControl1` and `MyControl12`.

How I can prevent Tab selection controls on lower-levels?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboardnavigation.tabnavigation(v=vs.110).aspx) attached property.

Let's see a sample:

```
<Grid>
    <local:UserControl1 x:Name="uc1" Panel.ZIndex="1" 
                        KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="{Binding ElementName=uc2, Path=Visibility, Converter={StaticResource TabNavConverter}}" />
    <local:UserControl2 x:Name="uc2" Panel.ZIndex="2" />
</Grid>
```

Where `TabNavConverter` is an `IValueConverter` which returns [Continue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboardnavigationmode(v=vs.110).aspx) if `uc2` is collapsed or [None](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboardnavigationmode(v=vs.110).aspx) if it is visible.

I hope it can help.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a lot of great general options here. As far as I know there's no setting in `KeyboardNavigation` to automatically skip controls based on the `ZIndex`. So it will be difficult to find a solution that works automatically for all different combination of `ZIndex` values (automatically determining the top control). I think the best bet will be to modify the `IsTabStop` property based on a Style trigger.

```
<Style TargetType="Control" x:Key="TabStopStyle">
   <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Panel.ZIndex)}" Value="3">
         <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="True"/>
      </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
   <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
</Style>
```

Unfortunately, since your controls are of all different types, you will have to set the style on each one explicitly:

```
  <local:MyControl22 Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Panel.ZIndex="3" Style="{StaticResource TabStopStyle}"/>
```

This example assumes that the `ZIndex` of the top control is 3. To generalize this, it may help to set the top control to a higher `ZIndex` (like 100) so that you don't have to change the trigger rule if more controls are added.

Comment: Pay attention: the `KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop` property attached - for example - to `MyControl22` and set to `false` does not prevent its children to to be tabstopped.

Comment: @IlVic That's true - I was assuming `MyControl22` had no child controls. I guess the `TabNavigation` property could probably be set from the Style Trigger as well if it's necessary for the specific custom controls.